# Build-essential for openSUSE

Tags: linux, opensuse

I am a newbie on openSUSE. I needed to get build-essential for the system but could not get it using `sudo apt-get install build-essential` or even by using `sudo apt-get update` and then following it with the previous code. I found a way to install most packages of build essential through `sudo zypper install -t pattern devel_basis`. But however, I am not able to obtain libframe package !! I can't directly download it because mine is an account on the office computer and I don't have the root access.
I am also attaching the screenshot of my terminal.. The error is towards the end.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBOEr.png)

Comment: Have you searched enough ? [See this](http://superuser.com/questions/352000/whats-a-good-way-to-install-build-essentials-all-common-useful-commands-on)

Answer (score 19):

`zypper info -t pattern devel_basis` to see what packages have the pattern

`zypper install -t pattern devel_basis` to install these packages

thanks to [what-is-build-essentials-for-opensuse](https://randomgeekery.org/2014/06/22/what-is-build-essentials-for-opensuse/)

Comment: Is that supposed to install C++ also? I need to run `zypper install gcc-c++` after that.

Comment: I keep seeing `pattern 'devel_basis' not found.` on SUSE 15 SP1. Maybe because I am using an unregistered system?

Comment: maybe this one? `zypper install patterns-devel-base-devel_basis`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this requires root login or just maybe **sudo** privileges. These can be granted by ur system administrator. You may just need to ask for them.
You need to add the repository first before trying the zypper install
The command is

**zypper ar -f URL alias**

***where***

**ar**  is short form of addrepo command

**-f**  instruction to zypper to add autorefresh flag to newly added repo

**URL** is URL of the repo which you type in a browser to visit repo
          in this case (***itc***): **http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/oss/**

**alias**   is name that is easy to remember. ***itc***: **openSUSE:Leap:42.2**

so...

```
zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/oss/ openSUSE:Leap:42.2
```

I had a similar problem with ubuntu/debian command.

**sudo apt-get build-essential libssl-devel**

it turns out in Suse **build-essential** and **libssl-devel** would be **devel_basis** and **openssl-devel** respectively. to install I then searched on google for just **openssl-devel** (as it was all that I needed at that time), and followed the link from https://software.opensuse.org. Hope this helps